# Expression request for a person who says things unrelated to topic being discussed

Tags: word-request

Is there any expression in English about a person who tells things unrelated to the topic being discussed? E.g., when you are talking about grammar, she suddenly starts to talk about a party she has been to.

The main reason I asked this question is that in my mother tongue we have an expression for such a person and I am trying to find a good equivalent in English. It is "a malapropos rooster." It is said because this person acts like a rooster which doesn't know when is the right time to crow. I searched a lot, but it sounds there is no such expression or idiom in English.

Comment: [says things, not tells things]

Answer (score 4):

There are several possible reasons for the changes in subject, and there isn't really a blanket word that covers all of them. Here are some specific terms:

> [evasive](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/evasive) - because they don't want to answer a question
>
> [inattentive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inattentive) - because they are not listening to what you are saying (this can be a medical diagnosis, or because you're boring ;-)
>
> [scatter-brained](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scatterbrained) - because they have difficulty concentrating
>
> [right-brained](http://www.angelfire.com/wi/2brains/right.html) - because every stimulus starts a train of brilliant ideas
>
> [random](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Random) because they are young and want you to know that they are not boring or conventional

Comment: +1 also _distractible_ - attention easily diverted by the environment.

Answer (score 0):

The thing actually said that doesn't fit the rest of the conversation is called a "non-sequitur".   All of the other words listed above could be reasons that the person has interjected a non-sequitur into the conversation.

Comment: True, but this does not answer the question, which asks for a term to describe the person so speaking.

Comment: A person who speaks in non-sequiturs would be fine. When one subject a person mentions is unrelated to another. The OP said: expression, not an adjective,not a single word.

Answer (score -1):

“Apropos of nothing” means having no relevance to the previous topic of discussion. I think this fits best for what you’re asking.